# Site down because of moving to another host bad for seo?

Tags: seo, hosting, add-on, web-hosting

I have bought a ipad website and it's moved to my server.
Now i have tried to make an addon domain, but it does not work on my first hosting account.
On my second hosting account it works, but on that server there is another ipad website so i don't think this is smart to do because of the same ip adresses.

So adding an addon domain does not work and the site is down now!
I have added a service ticket, but i think this will cost at least 8 hours before i get an answer.

Can anyone tell me how bad this is for my serp position in google.
The website has always been on the first page.
Will this 404 error do bad to my site?cOr is it better to place the site on the same server as the other ipad website?

Comment: Just what exactly is an "ipad website"? (sic) is it just a website all about iPads?

Comment: Those are both Dutch ipad affiliate websites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

It is not ideal to serve a 404/timeouts, [however your rankings should recover](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum30/32822.htm). You mentioned that the sites are different. Moving the site to a different server/IP shouldn't matter too much as long as you can minimize the down time of the said process performed (and should probably be preferred over downtime, if possible). I want to ensure this is communicated, but do NOT show site #2 as site #1 in the short term as you will [experience duplicate content issues](http://www.seobythesea.com/?p=212).

If you don't already have it, you might open up a [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) account. It will provide you with some diagnostics about your outage (e.g. how many attempts Google tried, the returned response codes, etc..) and if something major happens, which is unlikely, you can request re-inclusion.

Comment: I don't want to transfer the page rank. both are two different sites and i want to keep them different.

Comment: Thanks for quick respons. No, i will not duplicate site #2 on site #1. The only thing i can do is build site #1 on server #2, but i think this will also not work. Now i know that ranks recover i can go to sleep now and wait for my ticket respons :-)

Comment: @Justmac Though being down for 8 hours isn't ideal, it shouldn't be the end of the world if the search engines can determine you have been a "quality" result in the past. They do keep track of how often you are down, so try to minimize it as much as possible (goes without saying I suppose). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is very bad if the 404 is a result of an internal link. 
I cannot tell you anything about which server you should host it on though, as i have no idea if that scenario is bad. Could you possibly host it on the one server, then when the next is up, host it from there?